# Search from Excel Table {Excel 2016/2019}

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, return-value, excel-tables

Hi I'm using a formula in category (Grey Color) than states

`IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UPS",M2)),"UPS",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("POS",M2)),"POS",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Server",M2)),"Server",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Keyboard",M2)),"K&M",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mouse",M2)),"K&M",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Print",M2)),"Thermal Printer",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Laser",M2)),"All Calls","Thermal Printer")))))))`

Now This should search the inline conditions and give the desired results but all its returning is 'Thermal Printer'

This is where I'm using it:

[image]

Apart from the solution, what I need to know is that tomorrow if the categories and their conditions increase, how will I be able to cope up with it is there anything in Excel that searches the excel table and Returns a column as to put as the category

Like if there was a table (With Name) in Excel that could contain 'UPS' in Column 'A' and 4 conditions to be met for the excel to categorize UPS in Columns 'B','C','D',&'E' and if any conditions are met the formula should return 'A2' (That could be UPS or Thermal Printer or Keyboard n Mouse). How to resolve this issue and prepare for the future?

Comment: You should not show people's personal information here. Are those real names and phone numbers? Please hide them in your screenshot and repost

Comment: You should not show people's personal information here. Are those real names and phone numbers? Please hide them in your screenshot and repost